# AWS STS AssumeRole gets temp credentials with Nodejs aws-sdk package but fails with golang aws-sdk for same creds and role ARN

Tags: node.js, go, aws-sdk

I have golang and nodejs code to get temp credentials for same set of creds accessKey, secretKey and roleARN. And Nodejs code gives me temp creds and go code gives me below error

`operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: ebccfbf8-abed-4490-83ce-730d87d131, api error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:user/sts-user-1234 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<accountID>:role/sts-role-123` 
Can someone help me with this?

Below is the link for my go code.

https://go.dev/play/p/txV2cTtSiTd

package versions used :

`github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2 v1.20.0 github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config v1.18.29 github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sts v1.20.0`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sts"
)

// AWSProvider ...
type AWSProvider struct{}

// NewAWSProvider ...
// var NewAWSProvider Connection = &AWSProvider{}

var (
    defaultRegion      = "us-east-1"
    defaultSessionName = "MCMP"
)

// ConnectionValidation ...
type ConnectionValidation struct {
    ConnectionID  string   `json:"connectionId" bson:"connectionId"`
    VaultConfigID string   `json:"vaultConfigId,omitempty"`
    Provider      Provider `json:"provider,omitempty" bson:"provider"`
    Reference     string   `json:"reference,omitempty" bson:"reference"`
}

type Provider struct {
    Type        string                 `json:"type" bson:"type" validate:"required"`
    ConfigData  map[string]interface{} `json:"configData,omitempty" bson:"configData,omitempty"`
    Credentials []Fields               `json:"credentials,omitempty" bson:"credentials,omitempty"`
}

type Fields struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

// Validate ...
func Validate(connection *ConnectionValidation) (err error) {
    accessKey := "<accessKey>"
    secretKey := "<secretKey>"

    configData := connection.Provider.ConfigData
    if configData["delegatedAccess"] != nil {
        delegatedAccess, ok := configData["delegatedAccess"].(string)
        if !ok || delegatedAccess == "" {
            err = errors.New("invalid delegatedAccess")
            return
        }
        err = validateDelegatedAccess(connection, accessKey, secretKey, delegatedAccess)
        return
    }

    err = validateAsset(accessKey, secretKey, defaultRegion)
    return
}

// checkAndAddProxy ...
func checkAndAddProxy(config aws.Config) aws.Config {
    if os.Getenv("https_proxy") != "" {
        httpclient := &http.Client{
            Transport: &http.Transport{
                Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
            },
        }
        config.HTTPClient = httpclient
    }
    return config
}

func validateDelegatedAccess(connection *ConnectionValidation, accessKey, secretKey, delegatedAccess string) (err error) {
    config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion(defaultRegion))
    if err != nil {
        panic("configuration error validateDelegatedAccess, " + err.Error())
    }
    config = checkAndAddProxy(config)
    config.Region = defaultRegion

    config.Credentials = aws.NewCredentialsCache(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey, ""))

    client := sts.NewFromConfig(config)

    params := &sts.AssumeRoleInput{
        RoleArn:         &delegatedAccess,
        RoleSessionName: &defaultSessionName,
    }

    configData := connection.Provider.ConfigData
    if configData["externalID"] != nil {
        externalID, ok := configData["externalID"].(string)
        if !ok || externalID == "" {
            err = errors.New("invalid externalID")
            return
        }
        params.ExternalId = &externalID
    }

    _, err = client.AssumeRole(context.TODO(), params)
    return
}

func validateAsset(accessKey, secretKey, region string) (err error) {
    config := *aws.NewConfig()
    config.Region = defaultRegion
    config.Credentials = aws.NewCredentialsCache(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey, ""))
    config = checkAndAddProxy(config)

    client := sts.NewFromConfig(config)

    input := &sts.GetCallerIdentityInput{}
    _, err = client.GetCallerIdentity(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("---validate aws creds---")
    conn := ConnectionValidation{
        ConnectionID: "id",
        Provider: Provider{Type: "aws",
            ConfigData: map[string]interface{}{"accountNumber": "<accountNumber>",
                "delegatedAccess": "<ARN>",
                "externalId":      "12345"},
        },
    }
    err := Validate(&conn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n --- error validate aws creds---%+v", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("validate creds success")
    }

}
```

And here is Nodejs code

package versions:
`"aws-sdk": "^2.1429.0"`

```
var AWSClient = require('aws-sdk');
var proxy = require('proxy-agent');

var checkForProxy = function () {
  if (process.env.https_proxy !== undefined) {
    console.log("Configuring AWS client to use https proxy");
    AWSClient.config.update({
      httpOptions: { agent: proxy(process.env.https_proxy) }
    });
  }
}

async function getTempCredentials(result) {
  console.log('-- Inside credential-validator-service/getTempCredentials... --');
  try {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (result['delegatedAccess'] && result['accessKey'] && result['secretKey']) {
        AWSClient.config.update({
          accessKeyId: result['accessKey'],
          secretAccessKey: result['secretKey'],
          region:"us-east-1"
        });
        checkForProxy()
        console.log("AWSClient config-----")
        console.log(AWSClient.config)
        var sts = new AWSClient.STS();
        var params = {
          RoleArn: result['delegatedAccess'],
          RoleSessionName: "MCMP"
        };
        if (result['externalId']) {
          console.log("Found externalId in payload, validating ARN with externalId")
          params['ExternalId'] = result['externalId']
        }
        sts.assumeRole(params, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error occured " + JSON.stringify(err));
            reject(err);
          } else {
            console.log("Temporary credential retrieved successfully");
            resolve({
              "message": "Delegated Credentials fetched successfully",
              "delegatedcredentials": result['Credentials'],
              "translateCode": "CO200_FETCH_SUCCESS",
              "translateParameters": [],
              "statusCode": 200
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        reject({
          "message": "Required credential details not found to fetch role, please provide arn, accessKey and secretKey",
          "translateCode": "CO400_FETCH_FAIL",
          "translateParameters": [],
          "statusCode": 400
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log.error("error while calling assume role of aws : " + JSON.stringify(error));
    return {
      "message": "System Failure. Due to: " + error.message,
      "translateCode": "CO500_ERR",
      "translateParameters": [error.message],
      "statusCode": 500
    }
  }
}

const checkDelegateAndUpdate = (body, callback) => {
  if (body.credentials.delegatedAccess) {
    const payload = {
      accessKey: body.credentials.passwordFields.accessKey,
      secretKey: body.credentials.passwordFields.secretKey,
      delegatedAccess: body.credentials.delegatedAccess,
      externalId: body.credentials.externalId
    };
    getTempCredentials(payload).then(({
      delegatedcredentials
    }) => {
      AWSClient.config.update({
        accessKeyId: delegatedcredentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: delegatedcredentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: delegatedcredentials.SessionToken
      });
      callback(null, "Success");
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error occured while fetching temporary credentials ", err.message);
      callback(err);
    });
  } else {
    AWSClient.config.update({
      accessKeyId: body.credentials.passwordFields.accessKey,
      secretAccessKey: body.credentials.passwordFields.secretKey
    });
    callback(null, "Success");
  }
}

var testAccount = function (asset_payload, callback) {

  if (!asset_payload.credentials.passwordFields.accessKey ||
    !asset_payload.credentials.passwordFields.secretKey) {
    return callback(Error, null);
  } else {
    checkDelegateAndUpdate(asset_payload, (err, _res) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err, null);
      } else {
        AWSClient.config.update({
          accessKeyId: asset_payload.credentials.passwordFields.accessKey,
          secretAccessKey: asset_payload.credentials.passwordFields.secretKey
        });

        checkForProxy()
        var sts = new AWSClient.STS();
        sts.getCallerIdentity({}, function (err, response) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
          } else {
            return callback(null, response);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
};

var requestPayload = {
    "basicInfo": {
        "accountName": "camaws",
        "serviceProviderType": "aws",
        "serviceProviderCode": "aws",
        "isActive": "Active",
        "accountType": "subaccount",
        "userType": "asset"
    },
    "advancedInfo": {
        "accountNumber": "<accountumber>"
    },
    "credentials": {
        "credentialName": "awscred",
        "purpose": ["assetIngestion"],
        "status": true,
        "externalId": "12345",
        "delegatedAccess": "<ARN>",
        "passwordFields": {
            "accessKey": "<accessKey>",
            "secretKey": "<secretKey>",
            "additionalInfo": ""
        }
    }
}


testAccount(requestPayload, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log("success*********")
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

Comment: The ***relevant*** parts of the code need to be hosted on SO, not on some external site. Provide an [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0):

Access denied means access denied.
So probably your IAM policy does not allow you to assume the role.
Check the parameters of the sts assume call.
A working example of go assume role can ne found here: https://www.go-on-aws.com/aws-go-sdk-v2/sts/crossaccount/
And for security reasons make sure to never put access key and access secret directly in the code.

Comment: But nodeJS code gets the temporary credentials with "aws-sdk": "^2.1429.0" package. with same params and policy set.